# Can we say "we are just about a third way to the city"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

halfway (adj/adv): in the middle between two points

Say, the distance between your house and your friend's is about 20 miles. You are driving to your friend's house and your car is about 10 miles away from your house.

We say "*we are just halfway to his house*".

What if your car is just about 6.5 miles away from your house.

Can we say "*we are just about a third way to the city*"?

or your car is just about 13 miles away from your house.

Can we say "*we are just about two third way to the city*"?

Comment: You can only discard the article and preposition with ***I'm halfway there***. For any other fractions, it has to be *I'm **a** quarter **of the** way there*. Note that the indefinite article there provides a syntactically necessary *determiner*, but a *number* is also a determiner, so you don't need the article in *I'm **three** quarters **of the** way home*. Also note that the "divisor" is ***plural*** in such contexts (***two thirds** of it*, not ***two third** of it*).

Answer (score 7):

In that case you would more likely say "we are just about a third **of the** way to the city".

Answer (score 4):

Don't use "third way" or "two third way", usually most people use "a third of the way", "two thirds of the way".

Answer (score 1):

We can say 'We are halfway there', but for other fractions of a distance we have to be more specific.

> We are about a third of the way there.
>
> The car broke down when we were three-quarters of the way to Grandma's.